# Using only landscape in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, landscape

I have a video app,but I would like it to stay only in landscape orientation

When in landscape it looks like this:

[image]

But when I turn around, it picks Portrait orientation and looks like this:

[image]

it would only stay in the Landscape orientation, already tried and tried many things I have seen and nothing has worked, someone help me?

[UPDATE]

Need only a view not use the orientation PORTRAIT, somebody already had this problem?

**Does anyone have any other ideas? nothing worked here**

**[UPDATE] -> 30/09/2015**

my solution:

in AppDelegate.m I use this:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if(self.restrictRotation == YES)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

AppDelegate.h :

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

where I want to stay only landscape I used it (videoViewController.m) :

in viewDidLoad

```
[self restrictRotation:YES];

        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

and add method:

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

remember if the #import "AppDelegate.h" in videoViewController.h

and the views that you do not want is locked in landscape add:

in viewDidLoad:

```
[self restrictRotation:YES];
```

and method:

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
    {
        AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
    }
```

Problem SOLVED! thx all

Comment: Please specify *what* you have already tried, maybe adding some code as well.

Comment: what I am trying now is this:
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}

Comment: This is to rotate the device rotation forcefully if you follow the steps i have mention in my Answer you might not need this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 possible way

1.) [image]

2.) By programmatically

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;

}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This you need to do in you `NavigationController` Class it looks you are using `NavigationBar`.

If not then use it in your `ViewController`

Comment: I tried this too, but do I wrong? I use in ViewController

Comment: If you are using UINavigationBar than you must make a class of CustomNavigationController and inherit it from UINavigationController and use this code in that class and 1 more thing use that CustomNavigationController instead of UINavigationController

Comment: you only need to remove the checks beside the portrait orientations in settings. don't add code. it will work for all controllers in your app.

Comment: you realized that the viewPlayer is landscape? but not app, look in images

Comment: This way for full application to lock orientation in one dimension not for only one view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set transform angle for player screen/Player parent view to show always in landscape mode.

Add this block of code in view did load method to show in landscape mode.

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
    if (radians!=M_PI / 2) {
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

    }
}
```

and add this method to always show in landscape mode on device rotation.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{


UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
    if (radians!=M_PI / 2) {
        [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
    }



}else{

    [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(self.view.transform.b, self.view.transform.a);
    if (radians!=M_PI*2) {
       [[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*2)];
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You can add code when you will launch your player to play video

Comment: You can add in one of the following method which i mentioned above

Comment: you realized that the viewPlayer is landscape? but not app

Comment: yeah i used this code to show just my player in landscape mode when app in portrait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90893/discussion-between-abrar-ul-haq-and-felipe-xavier).

Comment: i made a demo application with this code which is working properly.

Comment: share with me please?

Comment: Share your email id please.

Comment: felipe.xavier@ymail.com

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.m add this method :

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This method determines which interface orientations are supported application wide , so if you return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape) the app will work only in landscape mode regardless of the supported orientations in any content View Controller , and the supported orientations in any content View Controller should only be a subset of the supported ones in AppDelegate.m.

if you want the landscape orientation to be forced in one View Controller only , then in AppDelegate.m :

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

and in the Video VC :

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

and finally present the Video VC using :

```
[self presentViewController:videoVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: problem is I need that only the video view is landscape

Comment: error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <PlayerViewController: 0x15662560>

Comment: I`m use : viewDidLoad -> [self presentViewController:self.playerView animated:YES completion:nil]; and -(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

in my ViewController

Comment: the error means that self.playerView is already shown ! call presentViewController with a VC that is not already shown.